# ng-file-upload preserve default or previous image

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am new to angular js and I was using danialfarid plugin for uploading file. This is the link to the git hub [danialfarid](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) repository. I was using this plugin to upload images. But the way the plugin works is, before choosing an image for the first time it will make the image thumbnail to be not displayed. But I wanted the image placeholder to have a default image. Is there a way to configure this plugin not to make the default images invisible before choosing an image.

Comment: `ngf-thumbnail="file || defaultImageUrl"`

Comment: @danial I put an image on the same directory and only called it's name, Like this ngf-thumbnail="file ll default.jpg" and it is not working.

Comment: Oh I got it, I should have put it with Single quotation. Daniel thank you very much.